# Bound for Double Sum.

Tags: inequality, summation

For $i = 1,\cdots,n$ and $k=1,\cdots,m$, $a_{ij} > 0$ and $b_{ij} \geq 0$. Do we have the following bound,
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m a_{ij} b_{ij} \leq \Big( \max_i \sum_j a_{ij} \Big) \Big( \max_j \sum_i b_{ij} \Big) ?$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. For $n=m=2$ and
$$
 A = B = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & x \\
x & 1 
\end{pmatrix}
\quad
$$
the left-hand side is equal to $2 + 2x^2$, and the right-hand side is $(1+x)^2$, so that the estimate does not hold for small positive $x$.

Comment: Thank you! What if $a_{ij}$ is strictly positive.

Comment: You changed the question after I posted the answer. But you can simply replace $0$ by a small positive number.

Comment: Makes no difference, @jwyao. Obviously if $a_{12}$ and $a_{21}$ are small enough, like $0.001$, then the left-hand side will be close enough to $2$, and the right-hand side will be close enough to $1$, so that your inequality is still violated.

Comment: @MartinR I made up the question from a problem I am studying. I tried to make it general but obviously I made a wrong generalization.

Answer (score 2):

No, since $a_{ij}=b_{ij}=\delta_{ij}+\epsilon$ for small $\epsilon>0$ is an obvious counterexample when $n=m$. (The LHS tends to $n$ while the RHS tends to $1$ as $\epsilon \to 0$.) To make your statement true, it should be
$$
\sum_{i,j} a_{ij}b_{ij} \le \color{red}{\sqrt{nm}} \cdot\max_i\sum_j a_{ij} \max_j \sum_i b_{ij}.
$$

Comment: What is $n$ here? Is it the dimension of matrix?

Comment: @jwyao I thought $A,B$ were square matrices...